# Pulseaudio microphone

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

I am using Pulseaudio to stream audio between two PCs running Ubuntu, with one set as sender and the other as receiver.

I want to be able to stream microphone data whenever i start Pulseaudio, but if the microphone is already plugged in when i start Pulseaudio, this does not work.

However when I plugin the mic after starting Pulseaudio, I am able to talk into the microphone and stream it over.

What should I do so that by default microphone data is streamed?